# How does streaming services works?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, webrtc, rtp

I'm working on screenshare application. Currently it works as following: c++ app grabs scrrenshots from screen, compress them and send to the server via TCP (written on node.js). Clients (those who wants see shared data) have link they paste in browser and connect to the server. Than server broadcasts data to the clients. The problem is in that, server can handle about 10-15 clients simultaneously when I need about 1000-1500.

I know that streaming platforms (like twitch or youtube) can process up to 1000000 (or even more) connections. I'd like to know the way they do it. To be more specific: 1) the protocols which is optimal to use both for shared data -> server and server->browser clients transfers; 2) any other tips and tricks (code examples, articles, etc.) to implement it.

Comment: What makes you think youtube or twitch are using only _one_ server? They have an army of servers. Now, do the math. How many clients can your server handle over one network connection at max? Theoretically and practically?

Comment: 15 clients were more less ok, but then speed is not real time like (not even close). I knew that youtube/twitch has a lot of servers, but still performance of their servers much better than mine. Do u think they use the same architecture as I do?

Comment: Check our [howvideo.works](http://howvideo.works)

Comment: Well, I don't know what your architecture is. But if you have lags @ 10 - 15 Clients already, then there is room for improvement. At what rate does your grabber make screenshots? Does compression actually help (i.e. does compression take longer than sending an uncompressed image)? How do you serve your clients? Do you actually stream (i.e. RTP/RTSP) or do you just send an "endless" list of images (something like MJPEG)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want real time data from the client to the Server (data -> server), suggest you can implement rtp over udp/tcp or mpeg2ts over udp/tcp.

For the Server to support broadcasting data to multiple client ( server->browser), suggest you to implement MPEG DASH/HLS Streaming ( Nginx , Appache - HTTP Server).

MPEG DASH/HLS - support streaming of media data based on bandwidth available. Most of the browser support MPEG DASH/HLS streaming through javascript player.

There are many open source solution available for the same.